# Codeigniter: Loading default static page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter

I created a new "/blog" directory in Codeigniter 3. I want to install a new Wordpress blog into this new folder.

When I try to load new folder www.mysite.com/blog/, I get an error 404 message. Logs show:

```
ERROR - 2016-07-15 17:42:40 --> 404 Page Not Found: Blog/index
```

My .htaccess file content is:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

How can I load (index.php) in my Blog directory by default, without typing index.php in browser's address? Please help me.

Comment: Can you try "RewriteBase /blog/" instead of "RewriteBase /" ?

Comment: This .htaccess file is located on root folder, and changing to "RewriteBase /blog/" showed Wordpress on www.mysite.com

Comment: Oh sorry, your question was written strangly, so I understood the contrary.

Comment: Can you show the content of .htaccess located in /blog/ directory then pls ? If you don't have one then you have to create one there for Wordpress.

Comment: I would show but there is no .htaccess file located in /blog/ directory. Can you help to create one for Wordpress.Is it solves this issue?

Comment: With proper content in this new htaccess yes it will solve the issue. I created an answer to discuss the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a .htaccess file in your subfolder "/blog".
The content could be like that :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /blog/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@-------- to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: I provided new content for .htaccess file. Can you try this new content pls ?

Comment: Great :) ! Don't hesitate to put the answer as "Usefull" (+1) to indicate to others that it provided the solution to your problem !